# Software center shows "use this source" instead of "install"

Tags: installation, error-handling

Last time I installed Ubunu I notice that in Ubuntu app center, most apps are missing install button, instead it is "Use this source" button and i can't install anything.

I've tried to use update command in terminal but it didn't work, they say it was internet error but I'm using Firefox right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add ubuntu software repository to your software sources. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) is the instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
but it Didn't work i'll try reinstall 12.10

Comment: What did you do exactly?
What is the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?